# Install SQL server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a problem
When I want to install SQL this error occur

> "TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Setup
>
> The following error has occurred:
>
> Error writing to file: Microsoft.MasterDataServices.Configuration.dll.   Verify that you have access to that directory.
>
> Click 'Retry' to retry the failed action, or click 'Cancel' to cancel this action and continue setup.
> "

[image]

Comment: The image shows a different error. Could you get a fresh copy of the installer and try again with that?

Comment: I feel like this would be a better question for Microsoft support if you've paid for a license

Answer (score 0):

To add the rights to the local administrator account, follow these steps:

1. Log on to the computer as a user who has administrative credentials.
2. Click **Start**, click **Run**, type Control admintools, and then click **OK**.
3. Double-click **Local Security Policy**.
4. In the **Local Security Settings** dialog box, click **Local Policies**, double-click 
   **User Rights Assignment**, and then double-click Backup Files and Directories.
5. In the B**ackup Files and Directories** Properties dialog box, click **Add
   User or Group**.
6. In the **Select User or Groups** dialog box, type the user account that is being used for 
   setup, and then click **OK** two times.
7. On the **File** menu, click **Exit** to close the **Local Security Settings** dialog box.

Comment: Where is, "cause"section?

Comment: Wherever you  have impact on permission issue, try this